# Telegraf save only last line of csv input

Tags: csv, influxdb, telegraf

I have a script that print a result like that:

```
somename,bps,running_time
AAA,1886,01:35
BBB,6235,01:35
CCC,2532,01:35
```

Here is my telegraf config :

```
[[inputs.exec]]

commands = [ "bash /opt/latency/test.sh" ]

timeout = "5s"
name_override = "latency"
data_format = "csv"
csv_header_row_count = 1
csv_trim_space = true
csv_column_names = ["somename","bps","running_time"]
csv_column_types = ["string","int","string"]
csv_skip_errors = true
csv_comment = ""
csv_skip_rows = 0
```

When I check on grafana which variables are put on the [influxdb](/questions/tagged/influxdb), there is only the last line aka with `somename=CCC`.

How can I add three lines into influxdb and not only last one?